# Sendgrid Email Excel VBA SMTP

Tags: excel, smtp, email, sendgrid, vba

I'm trying to integrate Sendgrid SMTP with excel for sending emails directly from my excel sheet. The code given below returns an error saying "Message couldnot be sent to SMTP Server".
[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrq1i.png)

```html
Sub Manufactureremail1()
'sends email to manufacturer using Sendgrid
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 'While (True)
    Dim iMsg As Object
    Dim iConf As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    '    Dim Flds As Variant

    Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

        iConf.Load -1    ' CDO Source Defaults
        Set Flds = iConf.Fields
        With Flds
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") _
                           = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "myusername"
            .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "mypassword"
            .Update
        End With

    

    With iMsg
        Set .Configuration = iConf
        .To = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Selection.Cells(2, 1), Worksheets("Contacts").Range("email_data"), 2, False)
        .CC = ""
        '.BCC = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Selection.Cells(2, 3), Worksheets("Contacts").Range("email_data"), 2, False)
        .From = """Yash"" <yashagarwal080@gmail.com>"
        .Subject = "Order of " & Selection.Cells(2, 3)
        
        '.addattachment Worksheets("Contacts").Range("I6")
        '.addattachment Worksheets("Contacts").Range("I7")
        
        .htmlBody = "Message"
        .send
       'MsgBox "Emails Sent!", vbInformation, "Success"
    
    End With
 'DoEvents
 'Wend
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try with `.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465`

Comment: @Jeeped Tried already . Didn't Work!

Comment: this worked for me too after adding reference to Microsoft CDO in the tools. Have you tried using Indic language within the html body string?

Answer (score 0):

Set your configuration to use SSL by adding:

.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1

Comment: This didn't work either. Error "The transport failed to connect to the server"

Answer (score 0):

Yash, I tested your code with out mail server config and it worked fine to me only two things I had done.
1. I had referenced Microsoft CDO in the tools -> Reference.
2. I changed the port address to 25

Comment: this worked for me. Any idea how to use Indian language fonts within the string variables, for email body.